# Let W be a basis in $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {u....u1} be an orthogonal basis for W, express x in W as a linear combination of {u....u1}

I guess I am confused on how orthogonality works in linear algebra, I know in vector calc it is simply when the dot product of the two vectors is = to 0, but it seems different in LA.

Thanks.

Comment: It works the same way, it just depends on what inner product you are using. Two vectors $u$, $v$ are *orthogonal* with respect to a given inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ if $\langle u,v\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal U = \{\mathbf u_1, \dots, \mathbf u_n\}$ is a basis for $W$ then we can express *any* vector $\mathbf w\in W$ as $$\mathbf w=w_1\mathbf u_1+w_2 \mathbf u_2 + \cdots + w_n\mathbf u_n$$ for some unique scalars $w_1, \dots, w_n$.

The fact that $\mathcal U$ is an *orthogonal* basis means that $\mathbf u_i \cdot \mathbf u_j=0$ for any $i\ne j$.  That's useful because then $$\begin{align}\mathbf w\cdot \mathbf u_i &= (w_1\mathbf u_1+w_2 \mathbf u_2 + \cdots + w_n\mathbf u_n)\cdot \mathbf u_i \\ &= w_1\mathbf u_1 \cdot \mathbf u_i + \cdots + w_n\mathbf u_n\cdot \mathbf u_i \\ &= 0 + \cdots + 0 + w_i\mathbf u_i\cdot \mathbf u_i + 0 + \cdots + 0 \\ &= w_i\|\mathbf u_i\|^2\end{align}$$

Therefore we get the Fourier expansion of $\mathbf w$: $$\mathbf w = \frac{\mathbf w\cdot \mathbf u_1}{\|\mathbf u_1\|^2}\mathbf u_1 + \cdots + \frac{\mathbf w\cdot \mathbf u_n}{\|\mathbf u_n\|^2}\mathbf u_n$$

Comment: JFK its just a vector projection? Alright well that makes things easy, thanks.

Comment: No problem. :-)